# Android-linear layout arrangement varies in emulator and device

Tags: android, adjustviewbounds

I am developing project with 26 cards design alphabets in linear layout fashion in android. I had included `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="centercrop"`.
Forunately it works well in emulator and does not show up in the real device. What would be the issue to make it work as well in device? Could you assist me regarding this? Below is the piece of code working in emulator not in device.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Linear_layout_equal" >

<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/NumberPad"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumberRow123"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/lettera" 
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/letterb" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/letterc" 
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/lettere" 
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/lettere"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/letterf"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:src="@drawable/letterg"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterh"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:gravity="center">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/letteri"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterj" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterk" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterl" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:gravity="center">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterm" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/lettern" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/lettero" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterp" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterq" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterr" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letters" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/lettert" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letteru" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterv" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button6"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterw" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterx" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/NumerRow456"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:gravity="center">

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/lettery" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/letterz" 
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button9"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/blankspace"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/button5"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:src="@drawable/blankspace"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp" 
             android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

As to believe the real screenshots of image, am attaching the image

Comment: Are you using same resolution device & emulator???

Comment: Yes..using Hdpi device and emulator with hdpi.